# Laravel Eloquent model : 2field, one fk refer 2 fields on other table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.8

I want to use Laravel Eloquent models and relationships to join data from all the tables in my project; however, I have a problem translating these relations. For example, I have two tables; the first is the Books table, and the other is the Author table.

```php
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('code', 20)->unique('ak_books__code')->nullable(false);
    $table->smallInteger('books_type_id');
    $table->float('detection_limit', 10, 0);
    $table->smallInteger('books_classification_id');
    $table->smallInteger('books_number');
    $table->foreign(['books_classification_id', 'books_number'], 'fk_books__classification_scales')
        ->references(['calibration_id', 'number'])->on('classification')
        ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
});

Schema::create('classification', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->smallInteger('calibration_id');
    $table->smallInteger('number');
    $table->string('name', 50);
    $table->primary(['calibration_id', 'number'], 'pk_classification_scales');
    $table->foreign('calibration_id', 'fk_classification_calibration')->references('id')
        ->on('calibration_parameters')->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');
});
```

How can I make a relationship on the Books table to take the `number` and `calibration_id`?

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships

Answer (score 0):

Like books-clasification, I will show you an example about a relation between tasks-projects (what is the project of this task):

TASK

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamp('start_date');
        $table->timestamp('end_date');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('tasks');
}
```

PROJECTS

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->tinyInteger('active')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
}
```

I hope it helps you, regards!

Comment: hello, 

thanks you for your help but in your example, you don't have a composite foreign key :s 

it's m'y probleme. i can use composite foreign key and i think laravel eloquent can't use that :S

Comment: Ah ok! I didn't understand you well. Take a look this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736866/composite-foreign-key-laravel